# ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Currently learning DeepLearning for around 2-3 days and got this error while i try to training my data

> ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0

google collab said that the error are here

> ```
>  56     validation_steps=totalVal // batch_size,
>  57     verbose=1,
> ```
>
> ---> 58     callbacks=[tensorboard])

and i have the code here just like below to make a model that i need

**Code**

```
import os
from imutils import paths
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from time import time
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

IM_WIDTH=224
IM_HEIGHT=224
EPOCH=2
batch_size=32

ORIG_INPUT_DATASET="/content/drive/MyDrive/DataFix/DataJadi"
BASE_PATH="/content/drive/MyDrive/DataFix/DataJadi/"

TRAIN_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "training"])
VAL_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "validation"])
TEST_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "testing"])

totalTrain = len(list(paths.list_images(TRAIN_PATH)))
totalVal = len(list(paths.list_images(VAL_PATH)))

def ClassicalModel(input_shape):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  
  return model

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1 / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_PATH,
                                                    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VAL_PATH,
    target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
)
tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))
model = ClassicalModel(input_shape=(batch_size, IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=totalTrain // batch_size,
    epochs=EPOCH,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=totalVal // batch_size,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard])
model.save_weights('GerakanUjian.h5')
model.save('GerakanUjian.h5')
```

still does not found the solution and how to fix it till now :(
any answer would be appreciated
thank youu so much guyss

Comment: Did you validate that the data is being found and loaded correctly?

Comment: yessir it is in the base_path where inside basepath there is 3 folder and that is training,validation, and testing, and inside the training and validation folder there's 3 movement that i want to detect
and inside the movement folder there's file that already labeled by me with LabelImg and has xml file extension

Comment: That is not what I am asking, ImageDataGenerator produces a message like "found X images in Y classes" signaling that the class found your data, what do you get in your log messages?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy
ah i see, sorry, i got this
~~~
Found 0 images belonging to 3 classes.

Found 0 images belonging to 3 classes.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1915: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
~~~

Comment: It is not finding your images, what format are they?

Comment: sorry for bad commenting format im new at this, its xml because after i label the image the extension change from jpg to xml

Comment: XML contains your labels, not the images, your images are still JPEG

Comment: ah i see, so thats the problem , may i ask what is label use for after i make it then? the tell nothing about this...

Comment: We cannot guess what labels you produced, that is only something you know.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i see, so i can only use jpeg to make the model, should i rename every picture too? because all my jpeg name are "data1, data2, etc" till 42k image data